# Why doesn't Neo take a more advanced gun with him when going to save Morpheus?

Tags: the-matrix, plot-device

While going back into the Matrix to save Morpheus, Neo and Trinity are sent to a huge room with lots and lots of guns, but in terms of technological level, they are all the same types of guns that agents or the military would have access to in the simulated world of the matrix.

In the 'real world', there are a few scenes before that where we see Cypher using a huge futuristic laser to take out two of his collegues.

**Why don't Neo and Trinity take something like that into the Matrix? Even the agents don't have a gun like that.**

From my understanding of the story, when Morpheus and his team enter the Matrix, they are not entering through the regular channel that the machines use to keep the humans in the simulated reality, rather they are hacking into the Matrix, and so are able to track their position from Morpheus's ship as well as obtain as much guns and ammunition as they want. Why can't  they take a more advanced futuristic gun with them?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Matrix is a world with rules. There are **laws of nature** written into the simulation.

Those weapons on the racks are nothing more than programs written by the Zion rebels. As such those programs exist within those rules and laws of nature imposed by the operating environment where they function (Matrix).

- As an example: I can use a nuke to kill everyone in a city in real world. But when I play World of Warcraft, I cannot - because WoW designers didn't provide that functionality to me with my level of access (however, THEY can write a WoW spell or back-end script to do that! which explains the advanced bug technology that you indicated was anachronistic).
- To bring the example more ontopic - imagine that Matrix programmers wrote the OS such that nuclear fission is impossible. Or even simply that there are no fissionable materials in the Matrix in the needed amount. Then - even if it's possible - and Morpheus knows it's possible - they can not create a Nuke to use in the Matrix.

---

Yes, **some** well trained people are able to bend those rules **a little** (Morpheus seems the most capable). But only a little. They still mostly follow the rules of the Matrix.

The only exception is The One (Neo) - he could theoretically create any weapon he wanted. But by the time he grabs the guns he hasn't even learned to jump between buildings like Morpheus, or to do bullet time (yet). He only realizes his power after the gunrack scene, on the building roof.

Bending reality by wielding a fictional weapon is entirely beyond his ability in that specific scene.

Comment: I'm not sure about this one. Certain advanced technology does exist in the Matrix, despite being anachronistic; http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Bug

Comment: @Richard - Architect can bend his own rules a lot easier than Neo or Trinity could.

Comment: The physics of the Matrix reflect the physics of the real world. Since the lightning gun works in the real world, there's no reason to assume it wouldn't work in the matrix. The Architect/Agents don't need to bend the rules to get the bugs to work

Comment: @Richard - The difference is that Neo DOES NOT know what physics and technology makes them work. In order to write a program, you need to understand the specs.

Comment: The point that I am talking about in the question is almost at the end of the movie. The point at which Neo hadn't even learned to jump from biuilding to building is at the beginning of the movie

Comment: @user13267 - He hasn't been able to do ANY of the advanced stuff until he met the Agent on the roof, **after** that scene with gun racks.

Comment: @dvk - I still fail to see how that affects what weapons he can bring into the Matrix.

Comment: @Richard - those weapons are **nothing more than programs written by the Zion rebels**. You can't write a program to shut down your computer if you have no specs and no APIs to shutdown functionality. But the creator of the OS can.

Comment: ok point taken. However, does Neo need to know how the device works in order to be able to obtain it in the Matrix?

Comment: `The difference is that Neo DOES NOT know what physics and technology makes them work.` Neo wouldn't have to write the gun functionality himself, someone else in Morpheus's team can do that. He just has to take it after it gets downloaded

Comment: @user13267 - Morpheus' team doesn't know either - you'll notice that they aren't all THAT well armed from the start of the movie. The reason I brought up Neo specifically is that, as The One, he could theoretically have made any weapon he wanted. But not yet at that time.

Comment: How can Neo "theoretically create any weapon he wanted"? There's no evidence that he can create anything...

Comment: Neo probably wouldn't be able to pull things out of the air like that, becasue he still has to stay with the rules of the matrix, he just understands the rules better than the average human in the system

Comment: At least that's how I had understood it, but I might be wrong

Comment: @user13267 - Yes. But he didn't understand the rules by the time of the scene you're asking.

Comment: @Richard - he can pretty much suspend the laws of physics (force field to cause the bullets to drop? Superman like combat abilities when fighting with Smiths?). So he can probably figure something weaponish out, even if not the exact lightning gun. Heck he can probably shoot lightning out of his a55, like William Wallace.

Comment: Yes he can bend the laws of Physics, something which Morpheus cannot do, but that is because Neo is special, he is an anomaly, unlike Morpheus, but there is still a limit to the amount he can bend the laws, a limit that is probably defined by the rules of the Matrix

Comment: `Yes. But he didn't understand the rules by the time of the scene you're asking`. I will restate the question here using slightly different words: Why couldn't whoever sends the guns to Neo in the Matrix, send him advanced futuristic weapons in the Matrix's simulated reality, instead of the normal types of late 20th century guns as used by the agents and military?

Comment: @user13267 - because they are NOT Neo. THEY can't go around Matrix's rules. I edited that into the answer already.

Comment: but like @Richard mentioned in his comment, the rules of physics in the Matrix are based on the real world, and if the laser works in the real world, it should be possible to simulate it in the matrix as well; unless the rules in the Matrix are a subset of the real world, and such a laser could not be simulated ata ll

Comment: @user13267 - can YOU build a laser in a real world (or better yet, a nuke)? No. You don't have the know-how, and/or the technology, and/or the materials. Let's say The Matrix physics prohibits fissionable materials. BAM. No nukes in the Matrix.

Comment: @dvk - I could build a laser from scratch; http://www.repairfaq.org/sam/lasercon.htm#concit1

Comment: Taking the particular example of the laser, we know that the laser exists in the real world, so IF the Matrix's physics follows that of the real world, technology present in the real world should be simulatable (is that even a word?) in the matrix. `Let's say The Matrix physics prohibits fissionable materials. BAM. No nukes in the Matrix` This comment would imply that Matrix physics is only a subset of the real world physics, so everything possible in the real world will not be possible in the Matrix

Comment: @user13267 - do you have any canon proof that Matrix physics is 100% identical to real world one?

Comment: may be that should be another question

Comment: "the rules of physics in the Matrix are based on the real world". But "based on" is not the same as "is identical to". Obviously, Neo and other characters bend the rules beyond what's actually possible in our world (if that's what you mean by "real world"). We're told that the Architect had to change the simulation to be dreary because humans would reject it otherwise, but real-world physics obviously allow gorgeous skies and weather. So we know that the simulation subsets and supersets "reality". It's a program.

Comment: NSA are you listening? DVK said he can nuke a city in real life. On the flip side, some cities have very high traffic congestion, so it might balance out.

Comment: We know fission works in the Matrix.  Otherwise, the nuclear power plant they attacked in *Reloaded* was working on magic.

Comment: Can I ask if there's any canon information regarding how far the extent of the rules in The Matrix goes as far as you know blocking fissionable materials, or being able to use nukes?  Personally I think they wouldn't try to use a nuke because that would endanger the lives of blue-pills... Which they are trying to protect / save.

Comment: @DoctorWho22 - that was a rhethorical example. Just the very first "Advanced" weapon that I would personally consider using if I needed something advanced. I was not implying that nukes are specifically against Matrix rules, just that they **could be** if Architect decided to, by fiddling either with physics OR with geology (no fissionable materia). If you notice, I specifically used WoW as "can not" world, NOT Matrix.

Comment: I think a better question to ask would be how accurately does the Matrix laws of nature follow or simulate the real world laws of nature. Is the Matrix set of laws a subset, super set, or a completely different set of rules with overlapping properties, with respect to the real world (the real world being the place where Zion exists)?

Comment: There is no evidence that nukes wouldn’t work inside the Matrix, but how are nukes supposed to help when you want to free a friend captured in a building? Similar things apply to the laser cutter: it doesn’t look like having the precision and range of the bullet based weapons they finally decide to use for the mission. To me it looked more like an engineering tool than a weapon which just have been abused due to the lack of other handheld weapons on the ship— at least in the first movie.

Comment: I just thought of another thing to add to this debate... You can't just simply mess with geology and physics too much as The Architect, recall that they explored the idea of making the world as close to the real world as possible because otherwise human minds would reject it... Imagine if one minute you're a scientist working at a nuclear power planet then next minute all the fissionable materia are gone that could potentially cause a problem.

Answer (score 20):

The "***huge futuristic laser***" you've described is better known as a [Lightning Rifle](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Lightning_rifle). It appears to be the only advanced weapon that the Zionese rebels have access to.

Since we see various anachronistic technology working inside the matrix (the [bugs](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Bug), for example) the decision not to use them must be an ***operational reason*** which seem to boil down to '[higher tech doesn't equal better](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AK-47)':

There are some pretty good reasons not to use them *inside* the matrix;

- **They're cumbersome**
- **They require two hands to operate**
- **They need an enormous, heavy power supply**
- **They evidently need time to recharge**
- **They only seem to work at short range.**

The Lightning Rifle is useful **as a weapon of last resort against machines** but they're only peripherally effective against humans. Tank survives a blast from point-blank range where a well-aimed submachine or shotgun blast would have undoubtedly killed him.

In short

- Lightning guns are bulky and a bit crap
- Classic guns are light, effective and deadly.

Comment: Those custom designed weapons are essentially like Tommy guns, they aren't some futuristic laser gun... Since The Matrix's simulation is pretty much set in the New Millenium the program wouldn't really allow futuristic laser weapons to exist.  It's much more feasible to create some sort of Tommy Gun esque weapon because those existed in Human History.

Comment: @DoctorWho22 - Laser guns are perfectly feasible with current technology; http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RY5RYb14mIE

Comment: Richard current technology NOW yes... but back when this movie was made that sort of technology was not readily available... Like I said Mouse's custom weapons are pretty much enhanced Tommy Guns.... Plus why would The creator of the Matrix allow the ability to create weapons that are THAT powerful?  Imagine how different the movie would be if they were just allowed to create whatever because hey it's feasible.

Comment: @DoctorWho22 - As per the comment chain below, if the physics of the matrix are analogous with the physics of the real world, there's no reason to assume a lightning rifle wouldn't work. The question then becomes "why wouldn't they use one" which is neatly answered by my answer "because they're pretty useless".

Comment: The Matrix is a computer simulation, there's much more than just mere physics being used in the Matrix.  Let's say to me it seems that the code of the Matrix only allows technology that is common in the era that is being simulated to be created / used, that would mean that they wouldn't be able to create Lightning Guns.  Just because they have the capability to create it because they know how, doesn't mean The Matrix would allow them to even be able to create one.  Which is I believe is evidenced considering there's no futuristic weapons shown being used within The Matrix.

Comment: Also if they are capable of creating advanced weaponry the way you describe it the lightning gun is just one example of a futuristic gun... People smart enough in the real world could just easily enough create a weapon using the technology they know about in the real world to create a weapon that is lightweight and capable of doing damage because as you said "it's perfectly feasible".

Comment: @DoctorWho22 - I've seen no evidence in either the films, animatrix, comics or scripts to suggest that the physics of the matrix is drastically different from the physics of the real world. Neo owns laserdisks, so lasers must work in the Matrix.

Comment: And there is no evidence showing that they are capable of creating futuristic weapons... The only "evidence" is the automatic shotgun but that's far from futuristic.  Also physics and limitations on coding or being able to use weapons is different.  I would say using Occam's razor with this question would yield it leaning more toward's the side of they can't use true futuristic weapons.  Considering that there's not true futuristic weapons in the Matrix shown at all within it.  There would far more assumptions for that then saying they can't create / use true future weapons, least I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14965/discussion-between-richard-and-doctorwho22).

Comment: @DoctorWho22 - Major edit to remove some of the irrelevant stuff.

Comment: Look at what fancy stuff the merowinger does, like writing his own funny food programs. I am sure lots of things are possible in the matrix, but also in this reality we know that fusion exists, yet our cellphones still operate on low capacity lion batteries...

Answer (score 8):

There are no futuristic weapons shown within the movie The Matrix while people are inside The Matrix.

The only shown example of a created weapon inside The Matrix that is different than what is natural to it is Mouse's Automatic Weapon.

[The Internet Movie Firearms Database](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Matrix,_The)

[image]

> The unusual pair of large guns that Mouse (Matt Doran) uses are
>   custom-built cam-operated electric driven automatic 12 gauge shotguns
>   with 25-shell cylinders and a fire rate of 900 rounds per minute. They
>   were crafted by John Bowring, lead armorer of the film. As an inside
>   joke, Bowring named the guns "Andy" (serial no. A1169 - Leetspeak for
>   Andy) and "Larry" (serial no. L2779 - Leetspeak for Larry) after the
>   Wachowskis, the writers and directors of the film. It can be assumed
>   inside the Matrix, Mouse designed these shotguns for himself like he
>   designed the woman in the red dress.

As far as evidenced in the movie and that particular website which shows pretty much every single firearm in the movie (while inside The Matrix) there is no evidence of any actual truly Futuristic Weapons.

We know that The Matrix is coded itself to be a Simulation of the Real World.  As such the weapons and gear that is used within the Matrix would most likely be restricted to what era the Matrix is simulating.  All the weapons in the movie are based on real life weapons that are common within the late 90's / early new Millenium.

The only evidence of "high tech" stuff would be the bug remover and stuff that the agents use.

[image]

It looks pretty much like some sort of sonogram machine with a tube that sucks stuff out.  This is an example of a "jerry-rigged" device, though I don't feel that it would be considered futuristic.

Also since Agents work for The Matrix itself it's entirely possible that they have access to stuff that others do not.  Like the drug used on Morpheus.

Overall I think that if we use Occam's Razor, the principle that among competing theories the one with the least assumptions will most likely be correct, that they can't really create truly futuristic weapons.  Sure there's evidence of jerry-rigged stuff, but there's no evidence of weapons that would be considered truly futuristic.  As opposed to the assumption that there are people who are knowledgeable enough who can hack / create weapons that are considered futuristic, are capable of doing so, but then choose not to for whatever reason.

The only person who is capable of ACTUALLY creating whatever thing he wanted would be Neo because he can bend reality within The Matrix.  Though there is no evidence of him willing anything into existence or having the knowledge of being able to create such advanced things.  I believe his powers would be more like The Green Lantern, his powers are pretty much limited by his will / imagination.

Comment: Very very speculative this. And not backed up by canon.

Comment: Not backed up by canon? I've shown pictures and stuff that's inside the matrix as far as guns, do you see anything that's futuristic?

Comment: When do you see Neo magicking stuff out of thin air?

Comment: I would assume that Neo can do stuff that most people can't... You know like flying around? What makes you think that he can't simply create weapons?

Comment: Because we don't see him doing it. If he could do it, there are ample opportunities (and compelling reasons) for him to have done so, especially when facing overwhelming odds.

Comment: A lot of the times in overwhelming odds his pure strength, durability, and speed would compensate... Since he is able to bend the Matrix to his will it can be assumed that he can create weapons if he really wanted to.

Comment: Then why didn't he? On at least three occasions (Chateau fight, Burly battle, final fight with Smith) , it would have been **incredibly useful** for Neo to pull a gun out of hammerspace.

Comment: No idea, but you can't dismiss that he might be capable of doing so considering his powers... I mean he gives himself the ability to fly, why wouldn't he be able to create weapons?

Answer (score 5):

## He brought a minigun.

[image]

Specifically, a GE M134 Minigun.  It is capable of firing 6,000 rounds of 7.62x51mm NATO ammunition per minute, although the prop guys apparently [said](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Matrix,_The#GE_M134_Minigun) Neo is only firing at roughly half that rate, or about 3,000 rounds per minute.

Is this as advanced as the crazy lightning gun Cypher uses, and is then killed with?  No.  But **it is far better suited for the task at hand**.

As we see in the scene where Cypher kills Dozer and gets blasted, the crazy lightning gun takes some time to recharge between shots.  Neo is going to take on three agents at once.  Agents are known for their ability to dodge bullets and move with superhuman speed.  In this scenario, the crazy lightning gun would actually be a liability, not an asset, because it would leave Neo almost defenseless while the gun was recharging.  A minigun is actually a much better option for Neo's purposes here, because it produces a virtual wall of projectiles, and being belt-fed, reloading/recharging is not an issue.

When a body is hit by a burst of fire from a minigun, it isn't just riddled with holes;  it is literally torn apart.  It isn't a matter of getting hit a few times.  It is a matter of being cut in half, having limbs severed, and having chunks of your body blown across the room.  There is no possible way that the agents could have been so effective in avoiding being hit for so long (and it is worth mentioning that Neo is an incredible shot, because he somehow managed to avoid hitting Morpeus, which is also very unlikely).

Again, the crazy lightning gun might have been more advanced than a minigun, but not by much, and in any case, the minigun was a much more appropriate weapon for what Neo was trying to do.  He needed to generate a massive amount of fire, and no other weapon in the world is better at doing that than a minigun.  He made the right choice.

Comment: No, they commandeered the helicopter that the minigun was mounted on. That's why Trinity asked for a program to train her to pilot a B-212 helicopter.

Comment: @Null - he still brought it to the party, regardless of whether he brought it in from outside the Matrix.

Comment: The bold part of the question asks "Why don't Neo and Trinity take something like [the lightning rifle] **into the Matrix**?" They did not bring the helicopter and minigun into the Matrix. The Agents and their SWAT helpers brought it to guard Morpheus. What would they have done if the helicopter hadn't helpfully been there? Why didn't they bring their own minigun *into the Matrix*?

Comment: @Null -Your point is a good one.  As for why they didn't bring a minigun with them:  I don't know how Neo's oneness would affect this, but in real life, miniguns don't work the way they do in movies.  You can't just walk around with one, unless you are a bodybuilder muscle mutant.  And you certainly couldn't conceal one, or carry anything else while also carrying a minigun.  They are huge, heavy, and the rotating barrels and massive amounts of fire make them very difficult to control.

Comment: @WadCheber [You'd be surprised.](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/71641/31936) Even if you couldn't carry one in real life, that is meaningless inside the Matrix. Unless you can prove that Neo knew ahead of time that the helicopter/minigun would be around, I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: @Null - the video proves my point.  He is waving the gun around almost uncontrollably.  Not an effective way to use a weapon.  The m134 minigun itself weighs 85 pounds.  3,000 rounds of ammunition for it would weigh about 210 pounds.  Could Neo carry 300 pounds around inside the Matrix?  Maybe.  But he couldn't hide it from other people while he was walking to the building where Morpheus was being held.

Comment: My answer is basically that the crazy lightning gun would have been a less effective option than the guns he brought, and as it happens, he found the best possible weapon right on top of the building.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Neo knew about the helicopter before he started out. They all watched from outside the Matrix as Morpheus was taken there (in the helicopter). Otherwise, how would they even know where to go to rescue Morpheus? This also explains why the army guys in the lobby were already in full battle dress when they showed up - they came with the Agents in the first place.

Comment: Terminator 2, Iron Eagle, and Predator all agree. In the late 90s it was up for sale at ~$120k. If he had used an M2, everyone in that room would be dead, and everyone in the building behind it, and everyone on the ground when the top of the building fell off.

Answer (score 3):

The answer could be as simple as **practicality**.

- Since the Matrix is coded to resemble the late 20th/early 21st century it stands to reason that the firearms tech that was coded in was of the same era.  Rather than take the time (which they didn't have ) to write code for futuristic weapons they simply chose to go for the "off the rack" option.  This would have allowed them to jump straight from the Construct to the Matrix, and also to allow for **resupply of ammunition** should they need it without further coding.
- The weapons they chose were all easily concealable under their trench coats, whereas something like the Lightning Rifle would have required an external power source, and would have been bulky and cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix was not really a world *per se* but rather a world emulated in software. This means that everything they use on their ventures to Matrix has to adhere to certain rules -- i.e. whatever they got had to be compatible with the operating system. I'm pretty sure that whoever designed the Matrix made sure that there were no subroutines that would allow existence of nuclear weapons.

Another possibility is that writing software that allows one to start thermonuclear reaction in Matrix is so complex that it's beyond abilities of Zion folks. Because of that they created devices that use simple newtonian physics to function (one can't just disable combustion functionality used in cartridges as it would also disable internal combustion engines).

Comment: This would be a compelling argument, if there was a scrap of evidence to back it up.

Comment: This is the good place to start looking for evidence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator

Comment: Both lasers and electricity work inside the matrix.

Comment: The funny thing is that this is pretty much very similar to the answer that DVK put and he has 11 upvotes and doesn't have any supporting evidence for the "laws" either.  The only thing that he is 100% right about is that Neo can't bend reality at the specific scene he refers to.

Comment: These are actually pretty simple things. Electricity is all around us -- for example without it our nerves wouldn't forward signals between our brain and body.
 
To get better understanding about emulation lets take a look into ray tracing (technology to generate images by emulating light). The amount of memory and computing power required to emulate rays of light perfectly is nothing short of enormous and because of that the practical emulation uses "close enough" results. Emulation failsafes make sure that none of the functions can allocate resources that would endanger rest of the functions

Comment: @doctorwho22 - I'm very dubious about DVK's answer too. It seems to rest on an assumption about the matrix blocking modern technology and some odd statement that Neo can make weapons appear by sheer force of will.

Comment: Well Neo has the power to bend reality and pretty much break the system... Hell Neo can FLY in the Matrix and jump into agents and explode them... Creating weapons out of sheer will depends how far his powers go.

Comment: Well, think you keep forgetting that it's relatively inconsistently written fictional story. Personally I still don't understand why he didn't make the whole things crash in the first place. It would have saved us from those horrible sequels.