# Gun too Large for Helicopter?

Tags: jurassic-world

In Jurassic World they fit a M134 minigun to a standard civilian helicopter. Isn't this gun much too large for the platform it was fitted to in the context of the film. I'm not a firearms expert but wouldn't the recoil send the helicopter skittering backwards in relation to the direction of firing, especially given the skill level of the pilot?

I suspect my other question regarding this would need another question... Why is there only one helicopter on the entire island? Were there any other, more suitable aircraft available?

Comment: There are genetically modified dinosaurs on an island amusement park and you're questioning a gun on a chopper? :P

Comment: Oh I have more questions, I just thought I'd start with the easy one...

Comment: One question per question.

Comment: Might be a better fit for aviation.se or possibly physics.se as this question is about real world mechanics and seeks real world answers.

Comment: Apparently even a human can fire an M-134 minigun. See [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/71641/31936) about the Terminator franchise.

Comment: You're right. Your other question is a pretty good question in itself.

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic: it's asking if something that we clearly saw happen in the movie should really have happened in the movie; if you're looking for an *in-universe* explanation as to *how* it was possible that might be OK -- you'd need to edit your question to clarify this and it can get taken off-hold -- but just asking "could that really happen" is out of scope for this site.

Comment: and I agree, you *definitely* should extract your second question and ask it separately.

Comment: Since the question is on hold, I'll just suggest this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8rEWQaQTAw

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast that video just makes me want to ask "how did they miss?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Main Question:

#### The Gun:

How could a small, civilian helicopter handle a mounted [M134 Minigun](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/GE_M134_Minigun)? Pretty much the same way this guy fires one without a mount, with the gun attached to nothing but himself (skip to 2:20):

The weight of the gun and chopper tend to counteract the recoil of the much smaller projectile and explosions.

As [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/71641/31936) pointed out, the fact is that a handheld minigun is impractical, dangerous, and difficult, but certainly possible.

#### The Helicopter:

I haven't seen the movie, so I don't know if this is the right one, but several sources suggest that the chopper is a [Eurocopter EC130](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurocopter_EC130#Specifications_.28EC130_B4.29).   It was heavily modified for the movie, and the specifications of even stock helicopters in the line vary from model to model, but here's an example of what they can do:

> Empty Weight:        3,036 lbs
> Useful load:          2,315 lbs
> Max. takeoff weight:  5,351 lbs

The IMFDB says the chopper was actually an [EC120 Colibri](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurocopter_EC120_Colibri), also manufactures by Eurocopter.  Here are the specifications for that helicopter:

> Empty weight: 2,185 lbs
> Useful load:   1,596 lbs
> Max. takeoff weight: 3,781 lbs

Less beefy than the 130, but not by much.

So far as I can find, although both of these aircraft are used by multiple militaries around the world, neither is typically armed.  In fact, I found no evidence of either one being equipped with weapons.

#### Helicopters in General:

The rear rotors of helicopters (which spin vertically, like a table saw) are designed to keep the force generated by the main rotors (which spin horizontally, like a ceiling) from spinning the entire aircraft in circles.  The energy put out by these rotors is far greater than the recoil of a minigun.

On top of this, the main rotor acts as a [gyroscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroscope).  If you've ever played with a bicycle wheel, holding one side of the axel in one hand while spinning the wheel with the other hand, you know that the wheel becomes far easier to keep upright while it is spinning.  That's a gyroscope at work.  Helicopters do the same thing.  There's a very good reason why we use gyroscopes to stabilize stuff.

#### Conclusion

If a helicopter can handle the stress exerted by the rotors, it can certainly handle a bit of recoil from a minigun.

Comment: In terms of your last sentence, at least that's how it works in this scenario. Weight of gun/aircraft are not always enough. Take the A-10 Warthog, which could actually stall from the recoil of the guns, if fired long enough. I realize that's a place, but it's still a fun fact. And that gun is massive.

Comment: The gun in that video looks a lot smaller than the one in the film and on the wiki page. More worryingly i found a [website](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Jurassic_World#GE_M134_Minigun) cataloguing firearms in movies.

Comment: @Burgi - Patience, young Jedi.  I am still working.

Comment: @Burgi found new video.

Comment: @DangerZone - The warthog usually shoots in the direction of movement, and with a ginormous gun.  So the engines, which aren't its strongpoint anyway (it is always just barely avoiding a stall, as I understand it), are pushing it forwards as a ridiculously big gun is pushing it backwards.  The tiny loss of a tiny bit of its already measly thrust is enough to push it over the stall limit, which it is always skirting, even under the best possible circumstances.  The engines say "*forward, I guess*", the guns say "*backwards, I suppose*", and the compromise is very dangerous.

Comment: @DangerZone - but the helicopter's thrust is pushing it UP, and the relatively minor amount of recoil is pushing it in the direction opposite of where the gun is pointing.  So basically, the engines say, "UP!", the gun says "SIDEWAYS!", and both can be satisfied to some extent without catastrophic results.

Comment: @WadCheber thats a fair answer, although I am now a little disappointed that my mental image of the helicopter getting thrown sideways when the gun fires has been trashed :)

Comment: That is, a warthog firing its death cannon while flying is like a toddler firing a shotgun while jogging - both are in danger of being knocked on their butts.  The helicopter firing a minigun is like a six year old  firing a .38 special - sure, they'll both feel it, but chances are, neither will be knocked off course to a significant degree.

Comment: If anyone is interested, this is why the Warthog's gun is such a problem:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/30_mm_caliber#/media/File%3A30_mm.jpg  Compare the projectile size to the size of the crew man's hands.  If one of those hits you, you don't just die.  You are torn in half.

Comment: @DangerZone According to [this](http://www.stripes.com/blogs/the-rumor-doctor/the-rumor-doctor-1.104348/does-the-a-10-s-gun-slow-the-plane-when-fired-1.152557) article that seems to be a myth: Air Force Col. Steve Ruehl "I have fired as many as 500 rounds in one trigger burst, that takes just about seven, eight seconds, and [it had] no impact on the air speed of the aircraft,". A reddit article I found says something about the exhaust gasses from the gun causing problems since they get sucked in and aren't combustible and the need for workarounds there.

Comment: @WadCheber - Exactly.  The A-10 has a high-speed artillery cannon, not a "machine gun".

Comment: You guys are reading WAY too far into my A-10 statement. I simply meant that recoil is not always an insignificant force. :P  
Although if what @Voo says is true, my example may be moot.